# Unit of Angular velocity of Precession

Tags: applied-mechanics

Since the Equation for the Angular velocity of Precession of a Spinning Disk is:

$$\omega _{p}=\frac{m*g*r}{I*\omega _{spin}}$$

Where,

> m -> Mass of the spinning Disk. [$kg$]
>
> g -> Acceleration due to Gravity. [$m/(s^2)$]
>
> r -> Distance of the Centroid of disk from the pivot. [$m$]
>
> I -> Mass moment of inertia of the Disk. [$kg*m^2$]
>
> $\omega _{spin}$ -> Angular velocity of the disk. [$rad/s$]

$$\therefore \, \, \omega _{p} (unit) = \frac{kg*\frac{m}{s*s}*m}{kg*m*m*\frac{rad}{s}}$$

Simplifying,

$$\omega _{p} (unit) = \frac{1}{rad*s}$$

Shouldn't it be:

$$\omega _{p} (unit) = \frac{rad}{s}$$

The Answer that I got is 'Since radian is the ratio of lengths, it has no dimension. Which means the expression $\frac{1}{rad*s}$ Simplifies to $\frac{1}{s}$ and again could be written as $\frac{rad}{s}$

So, instead of $\frac{rad}{s}$, I could write $\omega _{p} (unit) = \frac{rev.}{s}$, which are similar.

Now, I want to solve a problem with this.

A gyroscope has a 1-kg disk that spins at 100 rev/s. The center of mass of the disk is 10 cm from a pivot which is also the radius of the disk.

To find the precession angular velocity.

> m = 1 [$kg$]
>
> g = 9.8 [$m/(s^2)$]
>
> r = 0.1 [$m$]
>
> I (Disk) = $\frac{mr^2}{2}$ = $5*10^{-3}$ [$kg*m^2$]
>
> $\omega _{spin}$ = 100 [$rev/s$]

On Solving, $$\omega _{spin} = 1.96 \, \frac{rev}{s}$$

since, 1 rev/s = 2$\pi$ rad/s

$$\omega _{spin} = 12.315 \, \frac{rad}{s}$$

Now, instead I want to give the input for $\omega _{spin}$ as $2 \pi * 100$ [$rad/s$]. (Solving the problem again with all the above given data.)

Which gives $$\omega _{spin} = 0.31194 \, \frac{rad}{s}$$

Which is kinda Contradictory.

Since rev/s and rad/s are similar units.

I used the same method above to derive the unit of $\omega _{p} (unit) \,\, as \,\, \frac{rev}{s}$

Now, please explain the catch in here..

Comment: I don't think you made a mistake is the simplification process, but having never studied precession I can't say why the angular velocity of precession isn't the same as regular angular velocity.

Comment: Radian is dimensionless so it doesn't matter both are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [@Sam Farjamirad](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/unit-of-angular-velocity-of-precession#comment57180_31859), a [radian is actually a dimensionless quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Dimensional_analysis). It's simply a notation so we know what we're talking about, but it's actually basically meaningless. Therefore:

$$\dfrac{1}{\text{rad} \cdot s} \equiv \dfrac{1}{s}$$

Comment: credit to https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16680/is-radians-dimensionless-quantity